# Qual è il senso di "fabbrica" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> Per cui gli fu facile supporre che i casamenti vecchi e malridotti del quartiere San Lorenzo rappresentassero senz’altro le antiche architetture monumentali della Città Eterna! e all’intravvedere, oltre la muraglia che chiude l’enorme cimitero del Verano, le brutte **fabbriche** tombali dell’interno, si figurò che fossero magari i sepolcri storici dei cesari e dei papi.

Potreste spiegarmi a che cosa si riferisce l'autrice con queste "fabbriche tombali" che appaiono nel testo? Ho cercato il vocabolo "fabbrica" in parecchi dizionari e, tuttavia, non riesco a capirne il senso nella frase sopra citata. Ho visto che può essere usato come sinonimo di edificio, ma le tombe di un cimitero non sono propriamente degli edifici.

Comment: Nel Verano ci sono molte cappelle gentilizie e altre tombe che sono, di fatto, piccoli edifici: https://www.google.it/search?q=cimitero+verano+cappelle&tbm=isch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Su Treccani alla voce [fabbrica](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fabbrica/) si può trovare la seguente accezione:

> 2. Edificio, di qualsiasi genere, in corso di costruzione, o anche già finito, se si consideri in rapporto alla sua costruzione (sinon.
>      quindi, ma ormai raro nell’uso com., di fabbricato): *una bella,
>      grande, solida f.; una f. ben disegnata; è caduto da una f.* (in
>      costruzione); *città ricca di notevoli f.*, di edifici.

Penso che fabbriche, nel contesto da te citato, significhi semplicemente costruzioni, edifici.

È anche pertinente al contesto l’accezione successiva, che fa riferimento sempre ad un edificio o costruzione:

> 3. In diritto canonico, la chiesa o altro edificio sacro nella sua struttura materiale; anche, la conservazione e manutenzione
>      dell’edificio sacro, che sono affidate alla fabbriceria, e, talora, la
>      fabbriceria stessa.

Nel [Cimitero del Verano](https://www.google.it/search?q=cimitero%20verano%20cappelle&tbm=isch) (come suggerito da @DaG) ci sono molte cappelle gentilizie e altre tombe che sono, di fatto, piccoli edifici.

Comment: Quindi, probabilmente si riferisce al tipo di tombe e cappelle gentilizie menzionanete da @DaG che, infatti, sono piccoli edifici.

Comment: @Charo esattamente.

Comment: Potresti includerlo nella risposta?